# Using wordpress theme for "standard" php site

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a wordpress theme that I really enjoy, however, I already have all the code written for my forms/DB and whatnot in PHP.

I've never worked with wordpress before, but I did just download a couple free themes to see what's going on. Am I missing something, or can I just cut out the code I don't need, and essentially use the frame as a layout, and insert my code where I want it? I don't want to invest a few days of work to realize I made a big mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress theme have it own structure to work for WordPress. If you need use the design, you may take out the style.css and modified the DOM for your own use.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured. I didn't want to do it to realize they use some special file types, kind of like how cakephp uses .ctp along with .php and .css.

Comment: You will probably spend more time doing this then learning how to use WordPress...

Comment: @travega I'm not worried about learning how to use wordpress. I'm sure I could pick that up fairly quickly if I wanted to, however, I have a fairly complex system already built, I'm just not content with the design. I found a wordpress theme that I like, and I just want to dump my content into a new design.

Comment: If you want to keep your head in peace, never *ever* open the wordpress internal files. Its a tool for 5 - 15 years kid.

Comment: I agree with @itachi if you like the design then reproduce it from scratch in a controlled way. WordPress themes are integrated with the greater framework code so markup is littered with wrapper divs and bloated css for universality. I have done what `G.C.Looi` is suggesting and it's a hiding to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would first load the theme up in a copy of Wordpress.  Then as others suggested copy the stylesheets, js and image files. The HTML I would copy from view source.

Wordpress has internal functions and copying from the .php files would take some work trying to hunt down what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use Wordpress and want to edit the themes, take a look at the following links. You'll need to work with Child Themes to be able to update your theme (otherwise your changes are overwritten).

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-click-child-theme/